# Docker / different kernel requirements

Tags: docker, containers, virtual-machine, scientific-computing, system-administration

I‘m completely unknowing and new to containers and I hope to get an answer here.

If I have an application, which runs only on e.g. centos7 (scientific software like `ANSYS`, `ABAQUS` and such), will it be possible to „dockerize the application“ in a container and run it on a recent Debian stable (since users will expect a more recent system for all their remaining work)?

As far as I read into the documentation so far, I understand that the container shares the kernel with the host, thus I will have no luck with the mentioned „containerisation“, aren‘t? To me it seems that in this case, I will have to use a VM instead of a container, including all the consequences in terms of performance, size, boot time, etc.. Does that hold also for other container systems like singularity?

Please, since containers are very new for me, any help and discussion is appreciated!

(I‘m asking myself, how is that done/realised at a SaaS provider like UberCloud?)

Thanks in advance for your reply’s and discussion,

George

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are tightly coupled to the host kernel, since Docker by design is basically using kernel namespaces to achieve isolation of various types of system resources. In general, "container" is usually a hint that the level of virtualization is thin, whereas "VM" is usually a hint that the virtualization may be happening in a way that is less tied to the host OS. A VM will generally allow greater freedom in running different OS'es within the virtualized environment, but that comes at the cost of greater (possibly much greater) overhead. The same limitations that Docker has in this regard applies to other containerization schemes as well, including Singularity.

Be careful not to conflate a Linux distribution (ie. CentOS, Debian...) with the kernel itself. Two completely different distributions may be include essentially the same kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! You confirm what my first impression was after reading a bit of documentation. Since Debian stable (buster) is definitely not using the same kernel as centos 7, I expect to run into the problem, that software which is certified for centos7 will not run at all, if used inside a centos7 container running on top of Debian 10... right? Or does it only depend on the syscalls initiated by the software... maybe worth trying it?

Comment: Your understanding is right. Whether a particular piece of software-- known to run under one virtualization scheme-- will run under a different setup depends on (not surprisingly) the software in question, the kernels, and also the supporting libraries (ie. glibc, etc...). As long as the two systems have the same instruction set architecture, it's a good bet that software will be interchangeable without much trouble (libraries might still cause some problems). I'd give it a try.